# Bash scripting parted for GPT

Tags: linux, bash, partitioning, gpt, parted

Using Bash & Python scripts in Ubuntu 12.04, we are delivering a disk image to customers as a file (generated by `dd`). Once `dd`’d to the new disk, we resize the partition to fit the disk. Now that we are using GPT disks, I need to provide a new non-interactive, non-X script.

The problem is `parted` generates an interactive message:

> Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it
>   should be. This might mean that another operating system believes the
>   disk is smaller. Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing
>   the old backup)? Fix/Ignore/Cancel?

But using `-s` or `-m` switch with parted I am unable to get it to resize the disk and fix the location of the backup GPT. I can’t echo an “F” into the command either:

```
echo "F" > parted  /dev/sda resize 2 0% 100%
parted  /dev/sda resize 2 0% 100%
parted -m /dev/sda resize 2 100%
parted -s /dev/sda resize 2 100%
```

And so forth. `gdisk` and `sgdisk` don’t seem to be able to resize. `gparted` works fine but it’s X of course and not allowed.

From the CLI I can squelch the interactive message by running in backticks:

```
`parted -s /dev/sda rm 2`  ( succeeded with error)
`parted -s /dev/sda mkpart primary 100%` ( fails because the backup GPT was not moved)
```

So I need the special “move GPT backup” service offered in the interactive message, and only offered there, but I need to run non-interactively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dru's approach will probably work, although I've not tested it. Two other approaches are to use a combination of `sgdisk` and `parted`, or to use `sgdisk` in a more complex way. Specifically, you could do either of:

- Use `sgdisk -e` to move the backup partition table data to the end of the disk, followed by `parted {device-file} resize...` to resize the partition. Using two utilities rather than one is a bit inelegant, but it should work.
- Use `sgdisk -e {device-file}` to move the backup partition table data to the end of the disk, followed by `sgdisk -d...` to delete the partition and then `sgdisk -n...` to create a new partition in its place. You can probably combine these into just two or maybe even just one call to `sgdisk`. One caveat is that this approach will change the GUID value for the partition. If it's important that it remain the same, you'd have to extract that data and reset the GUID value -- or given that you're starting from a known image, you could store the GUID value as part of your script and reset it without first extracting it.

Note that I've not tested either of these approaches, so I can't guarantee them any more than I can guarantee Dru's method.

Comment: Also a good idea @Rod Smith. I'll test these on Monday at work.

Comment: I am going to use this: `sgdisk -e /dev/sda ; sgdisk -d 2 /dev/sda ; sgdisk -N 2  /dev/sda`

Comment: Note that if you use the `sgdisk`-only approach, you must also resize the filesystem contained in that partition. Also, it's important that the new partition's start sector remain the same as the original. This is not guaranteed if you use `sgdisk -N`, although it might work out fine, depending on how the original partition was created.

Comment: I believe you wrote sgdisk? you should know! but.... df and gparted won't agree after you are done. As Rod says, you must do a `resize2fs` and I also do an `e2fsck` before the `resize2fs`. Not sure if e2fsck is required or just a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can run an [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script from your Bash script `parted` to answer the question.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn parted  /dev/sda resize 2 0% 100%
expect "Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be. This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller. Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)? Fix/Ignore/Cancel? "
send "F\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Thats a good idea @Dru.